# Как задать класс с помощью JS переменной в модульном css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scss

Допустим есть переменная popupName, в ней находится какое-либо имя, допустим "login" или "register".

Есть элемент:

```
<section className={`${styles.popup} ${popupOpened ? styles.popup_opened : ''}`}>
```

Вопрос: Как задать в модульной системе классов класс с использованием переменной? Чтобы класс мог меняться от значения переменной. Использую дефолтный module.css от react.

Answer (score 1):

```
import styles from 'Твой css модуль';


const popupName = "login"; // или "register"

// Используем переменную для динамического присвоения класса
const className = `${styles.popup} ${popupOpened ? styles.popup_opened : ''} ${styles[popupName]}`;

// Затем применим className к элементу
<section className={className}>
</section>
```